# Whats the difference between .ppk and .pem . Where .pem is stored in amazons ec2 cluster?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, giraph

I am using Amazon's EC2 cluster for running GraphLab.  They want the location of my `.pem` file, which is my private key.

After searching I still I could not find the file in ubuntu. I am using PuTTY.

Answer (score 58):

`.pem` file is what you have download from AWS when you created your key-pair. This is only a one time download and you cannot download it again.

Your software is asking for `.pem` file. Now you are the one who needs to locate that file. You might have downloaded it on you laptop/desktop...etc.

As I said above, `.pem` is not saved anywhere on EC2. It is a one time download and you have to keep it safe.

For `Putty` (windows ssh client), it does not support `.pem` format. Hence you have to [convert](http://glassonionblog.wordpress.com/2012/01/29/connect-to-an-ec2-instance-with-putty-winscp/) it to `.ppk` format using [PuTTyGen](http://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/x86/puttygen.exe). It's essentially `.pem` but in a different format so that `Putty` can work with it.

Comment: Hi slayed Thanks for the reply . I actually downloaded .pem and then uploaded it to Amazon S3 and then using sudo wget i got it on my machine. I think its able to access the .pem file .BUt I am now getting some other issues.

Comment: no problem. I'll be glad to help if the issue is with ssh. If it is relevant to GraphLab, then I do not have any expertise on it.

Comment: Loved your explanation… (y)

Answer (score 22):

You have two questions here. I know I am late on answering this but I'll proceed anyway.

## Question #1

> Whats the difference between .ppk and .pem?

The *.pem* and *.ppk* files are similar because they are both **private key** file formats. The *.pub* file counterpart is the public key file format -- but that is a different story.

The differences between *.pem* and *.ppk* are the following:

1. System/platform compatibility

   **.pem** is kind of the *de facto* standard

   - Linux BASH users — **.pem** file format
   - Mac BASH users — **.pem** file format
   - Windows/Linux/Mac PowerShell users — **.pem** file format
   - Windows PuTTY/Cygwin users — **.ppk** file format
2. File contents

   **.pem**

   ```
   -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
   MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAxZls7NgRS5rtDH+mCgEeqSO12BiPAY2dhZZbTkPEoDUVqG46
   PHGIBBERISHFKS3xE4eMMY+uWPriviY0W12EFqYBUJDq6GmGSQPMSI8Kep7OgVGK
   d2t3/Lq+I8ZqlFwAgPwS7n18mlgTV/YyA0HCCIa+kZGKqbsuylfsODUAJGQqOtUM
   FKX4+O45RrJwcQGI2M+pbD4+Ow28iEsNP3flQKvamNuezm2VallhGiO/E39UITrB
   27FWM1pLQo5etyE378h5q8BKMGKt1ZPxPhjiNjBefGZ1Dscw7CA5
   -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
   ```

   **.ppk**

   ```
   PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
   Encryption: none
   Comment: imported-openssh-key
   Public-Lines: 3
   AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDFmWzs2BFLmu0Mf6YKAR6pI7XYGI8BjZ2F
   llGIBBERISHobjo8c6DjH6iBW0UpLfETh4wxj65Y+uK+JjRbXYQWpgFQkOroaYZJ
   1DxehJUvZpuZqLSUGvZrUzbYmx25oVE5+x6UBSA0NUiTpq6jWFPH
   Private-Lines: 3
   AAABAFLQsak2CVGhldYWLbWlsH78+3qdGFpzSuCxGoVbu63VccVMpVWutHBcVVgZ
   s4GIBBERISHcVhru01cUVf8w22pOmuB0TC+qAmDZmaWTZbXslun2Dc1tGjWu4n/F
   S0KOXrchN+/IeavASjBirdWT8T4Y4jYwXnxmdQ7HMOwgOQ==
   Private-MAC: 5fGIBBERISHda60d2e8b049e655e4a8a78bb18dc
   ```

## Question #2

> Where .pem is stored in amazons ec2 cluster?

In AWS, the *.pem* files are not directly stored to a single machine.

You can get the *.pem* file either by:

1. Starting a new instance

   When you create an EC2 instance, you will be given a default *.pem* file where you can use to access the new instance.
2. Creating a new *.pem* file through IAM

Comment: .. and from what I can see having Base64 decoded private key (of pem) and private key section (of ppk) the pem key ends with the private section of ppk byte for byte. So pem must have a prefix full of related information that's encoded differently in ppk file itself (my assumption).